# How to make entire Mailchimp button clickable?

Tags: html, email, mailchimp

When you add a button on a Mailchimp template, only the text within the button is clickable. Not sure why they designed it this way...is there a good reason for this?

If not, is there an easy way to make the entire button clickable...I've thought about just creating a button image...and making it linked...but trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Could you provide the full code, or even just the code for the button, if possible? It would make it much easier to see what's going wrong, since there are numerous different ways this could happen in HTML.

Comment: Any update on this? Unable to make entire button clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Give this article and technique a go.
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/bulletproof_buttons_for_office_365_and_everything_else

I use it every where and it has a fall back for Outlook. 
Be sure to check the comments for any tips from users who have figured a few quirks out from the originally supplied snippet. 
Like my comment about adding stroke="f" to the snippet to remove the default stroke on linked buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a button fully clickable is to build the button with an HTML table and wrap the table in an anchor, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com">
    <table border="0" width="">
        <tr>
            <td><span>Click Here</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
```

It is not valid in HTML4, but is valid in HTML5, but not much of what goes into an HTML email is valid, so I do not worry about it.

The problem with this approach is that it is still hard to edit in most, if not all, HTML Email platforms, such as Mail Chimp or Campaign Monitor. A non-coder who sends email will have to go into HTML view to edit the email - not ideal.

In MailChimp, their editor breaks the parent anchor, stripping it out altogether.

Test it in your email platform of choice, it is a simple solution.

Comment: Mailchimp rearranges the tags so that the `<a>` gets put inside the `<td>` :(